# SAP Fiori Elements - Client-side error messages in the same Message Popover?

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

Is it possible to add SAPUI5 client-side error messages/validations into the same Message Popover handled by the framework when using Fiori Elements ? I try to use sap.ui.core.message.ControlMessageProcessor and I can see my messages in the Message Manager message model when debugging (both OData and Frontend), however the Message Popover only shows the OData error messages. How can I show both ?

Here is my code. For context, the following code is implemented in the Event handler "fieldChange" of sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable. The target works fine since the app successfully changes the value state to Error (red) on the correct control and displays the value state error message on the field. My issue is that it doesn't add it to the Message Popover. What am I missing?

(this is on ABAP Platform 1909 and SAPUI5 1.71 version)

```
// ____________________________________________________
var oMessageManager = sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager();
var oMessageProcessor = new sap.ui.core.message.ControlMessageProcessor();
oMessageManager.registerMessageProcessor(oMessageProcessor);
oMessageManager.registerObject(this.getView(), true);
var sTarget = oEvent.getParameters().changeEvent.getSource().getInnerControls()[0].getId() + "/value";

var fnAddMessage = function() {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   var oMessage = new sap.ui.core.message.Message({
                message: "Duplicate",
                persistent: false,
                type: sap.ui.core.MessageType.Error,
                target: sTarget,
                processor: oMessageProcessor
       });
   oMessageManager.addMessages(oMessage);
   resolve();
  });
};

this.extensionAPI.securedExecution(fnAddMessage);

// ____________________________________________________
```